# Unknown Template Encoding of .iso File

Tags: python, encoding

I have a file saved as .iso which looks like this on notepad++

[image: .iso file]

I can read it using python:

```
def openfile():
  with open('file.iso', mode='rb') as file:
     data = file.read()
```

And this is the result I get
[image: python result]

What is the encoding of the .iso file and how can I write a file in that format using python?

Comment: Judging by the file extension, this is a disk image file: https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/iso-image. I guess you can have a look at the original specification, which is mentioned in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_image

Comment: Why are you asking this question? The ISO file extension is used for CD and DVD disk images. It *contains* file, it's not a data file itself and certainly not a text file. All OSs can mount such files as disks. You shouldn't have to read or write directly to such a file unless you already know what it is

Comment: Since you mentioned Notepad++, you can just double click on an ISO file and Windows will mount it as a disk

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually figured out that the file is a fingerprint template of standard iso19794 and I guess that's why it's saved as .iso and that's why I was able to read it using the python script

Comment: In that case, whoever created it was evil and use a completely inappropriate extension. That's as evil as using `.zip` to store a list of zipper sizes as text.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agree with you. This got me scratching my head for some days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's a fingerprint template saved as ASCII characters. I converted the data I got from the python script into hex and used [this site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html)

to convert it back to the ASCII characters.

Thanks for everyone who took his/her time to comment. Much appreciated